# Getting a string from JSON object with args from another object

Tags: node.js, json

Say I have a JSON file like this:

```
{"ABCD":{
    "1_99":{"type": 3, "serverPath": "http://some.website.com"}
  },
 "EFGH":{
    "1_00":{"type": 2, "serverPath": "http://another.meme.website/"}
    "1_01":{"type": 2, "serverPath": "http://yet.another.website.com/memes"}
  },
  etc..
}
```

and I want to reference one of the element in that file:

```
let appList = require('./config/appList.json');
...
var uri = appList.ABCD.1_99.serverPath;
```

where element name "ABCD" and "1_99" comes from another object and it's not always the same, say:

```
var uri = appList. [httpPOSTRequest.app_id] . [httpPOSTRequest.app_ver] . serverPath;
```

which I wonder if there's any way that can do so please.

Comment: You're not far off. Try formatting like `var uri = gameList[ key1 ][ key2 ].serverPath;`.

Comment: Hello David, Read more on property accessors https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: Even better, re-write with validation checking each reference before you de-reference for the next.  so check ( gameList[key1] != undefined) then ( gameList[key1][key2] != undefined ) before finally the full reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate your search properties in a search object, then use this to access your appList object using JavaScript [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation).

I've wrapped this up in a getServerPath function which also conveys the intent of the exercise.

We'll return *null* if we can't find the path in question.

Also, bear in mind, there is a very useful function in the [lodash](https://lodash.com) library [_.get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) which can do an awful lot of this stuff for you, I've included an example below.

I hope this helps you!

```js
// Get the required server path given the searchInput object
function getServerPath(appList, searchInput) {
    if (!searchInput) return null;
    if (!appList[searchInput.property1]) return null;
    if (!appList[searchInput.property1][searchInput.property2]) return null;
    return appList[searchInput.property1][searchInput.property2].serverPath;
}

// In Node.js we would use require('file.json') to define this.
let appList = {
    "ABCD": {
        "1_99": {
            "type": 3,
            "serverPath": "http://some.website.com"
        }
    },
    "EFGH": {
        "1_00": {
            "type": 2,
            "serverPath": "http://another.meme.website/"
        }
    }
}

// Search object input
let searchInput1 = { property1: "ABCD", property2: "1_99" };
let searchInput2 = { property1: "EFGH", property2: "1_00" };
let searchInput3 = { property1: "DOESNTEXIST", property2: "1_00" };

console.log("Server path 1:", getServerPath(appList, searchInput1));
console.log("Server path 2:", getServerPath(appList, searchInput2));
console.log("Server path 3:", getServerPath(appList, searchInput3));

// Using the very useful lodash _.get
console.log("Server path (using lodash _.get):", _.get(appList, "ABCD.1_99.serverPath"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your appList or you can use other libraries like (https://lodash.com/). I have implemented it with simple loop

```js
let appList = {
    "ABCD": {
        "1_99": {
            "type": 3,
            "serverPath": "http://some.website.com"
        }
    },
    "EFGH": {
        "1_00": {
            "type": 2,
            "serverPath": "http://another.meme.website/"
        }
    }
}


Object.keys(appList).map((d,i)=>{
    Object.keys(appList[d]).map((data, index)=>{
        console.log(`server path ${i} : ${appList[d][data].serverPath}`);
    })
})
```